# Run testNG programatically in Eclipse using maven without a plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testng

I want to run TestNG without using the "TestNG eclipse plugin" in a normal maven quickstart project.

Whatever I read from http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically & other sources, I got idea of using classes as:

**MessageUtil.java**

```
package com.mytests.testng;

public class MessageUtil {
   private String message;

   public MessageUtil(String message){
      this.message = message;
   }

   public String printMessage(){
      System.out.println(message);
      return message;
   }   
}
```

**TestNGExample.java**

```
package com.mytests.testng;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNGExample {
   String message = "Hello World";  
   MessageUtil messageUtil = new MessageUtil(message);

   @Test
   public void testPrintMessage() {   
      Assert.assertEquals(message,messageUtil.printMessage());
   }
}
```

**App.java**

```
package com.mytests.testng;

import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;
import org.testng.TestNG;

public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG testNG = new TestNG();

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class[] testClasses = new Class[]{
                TestNGExample.class
        };

        testNG.setTestClasses(testClasses);
        testNG.addListener(tla);
        testNG.run();
    }
}
```

But here I am getting exceptions as:

**Exception Box 1**

[image: JNI Error]

**Exception Box 2**

[image: Java Exception]

**Exception in Console**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/ITestListener
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.ITestListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

I am not getting why there is a problem even though I don't get any compile time error. The TestNG dependency is successfully downloaded and helps in writing the code. But the class doesn't load on run time I guess. What can be done?

If not using any XML is causing an error, I can use it as well, but not the eclipse plugin for TestNG.

P.S.: I am new to TestNG and this is my first program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is happening because at runtime, testng jar is not available in classpath. You can resolve this by using `<scope>compile</scope>` instead of `<scope>test</scope>` in your testng pom dependency.

Comment: That worked exactly as I wanted!!! Can you tell me how can I use an xml file to provide it as config input to this program?